# Shell script search & replace in text file

Tags: android, bash, shell

I have to edit text file in android shell.

so I type this shell script.

but my Galaxy Nexus does not have Sed, Awk neither.

```
shell@android:/ $ sed -e "s/old_pattern/new_pattern/g" file_name > modify_file
/system/bin/sh: sed: not found
```

it doesn't worked.

how can i modify `old_pattern` to `new_pattern` in text file.

is it possible in Shell Script?

Edited Shell Script

```
#!/system/bin/sh
ARGS=4
BAD=65

if [ $# -ne "$ARGS" ]
then
    echo "Usage: `basename $0` TARGET_FILE,OLD_PATTERN,NEW_PATTERN,MODIFY_FILE"
    exit $BAD
fi

old_pattern=$2
new_pattern=$3
modify_file=$4

if [ -f "$1" ]
then
    target_file=$1
else
    echo "\"$3\" Does not exist."
    exit $BAD
fi

exit 0
```

Solution :

```
shell@android:/ $ while read STRING
>do
>echo "${STRING//old_pattern/new_pattern}" >> modify_file_name
>done < target_file_name
shell@android:/ $
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible with pure `bash`, but it will be very slooow on big files.

```
while read STRING
do
    echo "${STRING//old_pattern/new_pattern}" >> modify_file
done < file_name
```

ps. Oh, I just mentioned that your shell isn't `bash`. Seems like it is just `sh`. That won't work with `sh`.

Comment: Sir, I'm sorry but my shell script have a Error.

Comment: Would you please check Edited script?

Comment: Such substitution doesn't work with `sh`. It's `bash` feature. Android as usual has sed installed. Try to check it and launch the script as bash script (you need to change she-bang for it). Seems like pure `sh` can't substitute the variable value. Have you other utilities like `ed` or `awk` installed?

Comment: awk, ed also not found. but your answer is very helpful. THX!